# JQuery Sortable "sortupdate" event firing additional times every time sortable is destroyed then readded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding a jquery sortable event to a list using the following code:

```
$('.filegroups').sortable({ items: ".filegroup", containment: "parent" });
$(".filegroups").on("sortupdate", function (event, ui) { ... });
```

The event fires without issue. I then remove the event/sortable from the list by doing the following:

```
$('.filegroups').sortable("destroy");
```

Up until this point, everything works fine. Once destroy is called the events have been removed. The problem comes in when I add **$('.filegroups').sortable({ ... });** and **$(".filegroups").on("sortupdate", function (event, ui) { ... });** a second time. From this point the "sortupdate" event will get called twice. Should I repeat this whole process it will get called a third time.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have removed:

```
$('.filegroups').sortable("destroy");
```

But yout `sortupdate` is still attachede to `.filegroups`, you need to unbind it as well.

```
$('.filegroups').unbind("sortupdate");
```

This is a drawback of separating sortable and sortupdate, but I realize that it wouldn't be possible to trigger an update without doing so.